# Picture thumbnails in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04, When i increase the thumbnail size in the pictures folder, the icons on the desktop also increase. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the size of the thumbnail images in the Files application also changes the size of the desktop icons by the same percentage. This is the expected behavior in Ubuntu.

[image: change size of thumbnail images in Files]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's unfortunate that its an expected behavior though, i'll just have to zoom back out of my thumbs before i close the folder.

Comment: @christo If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.